# Remix Static Analysis: Why gas cost message?

Tags: remix, testing, gas-price

I am doing the static analysis of the following smart contract (SC) on Remix:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;
contract TxUserWallet {
    address owner;
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    function transferTo(address payable dest, uint amount) public {
        require(tx.origin == owner);
        dest.transfer(amount);
    }
}
```

I am getting the message Gas Cost. Somebody please guide me, why I am getting the Gas Cost message? The message is shown below:

> Gas costs: Gas requirement of function TxUserWallet.transferTo is infinite: If the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it cannot be executed. Please avoid loops in your functions or actions that modify large areas of storage (this includes clearing or copying arrays in storage) Pos: 8:4:

Comment: It's probably a bug. The transfer forwards only 2300 gas, so there's an upper limit.

Answer (score 0):

If you try:

```
    function transferTo(address payable dest) payable public {
        require(tx.origin == owner);
        dest.transfer(msg.value);
    }
```

And send the amount by value field?
Im not sure what you want.. but I tried this here on my remix, and worked.
Let me know. :D

Comment: Hi, this is not the answer. Kindly read my question and then provide the answer accordingly. What do you mean by worked? Why have you written just the function, not the whole SC? Zulfi.